# A problem in downloading a package

Tags: errors, packages, software

I have a problem in downloading the package fullpage, using the command `\usepackage{fullpage}`.
I was doing this while watching a tutorial on Youtube about LaTeX.
I will upload all the pictures for this problem, beginning from writhing the command.

In this website I read we should make the question clear even without pictures, I will try to do that.

After compiling a new window has popped up, its title is MiKTeX error report, in its first section it is written: "The requested package is unknown.", and in the second section it is written "name="preprint"".
I clicked the option OK.

Then a new window has popped up, its title is package installation, it says:
The required file
tex/latex/preprint\fullpage.sty
is missing it is part of the following package:
preprint
The package will be installed from:
(empty space)
the package will be installed for:
(Also empty space)
I have two choices install or cancel, I chose install.

Then I returned to my LaTeX editor (MiKTeX)
and I saw the following two error message:

! LaTeX Error: File `fullpage.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>
l.4

! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

Please help if you can.
[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

Comment: go to the miktex console and try to install the preprint package manually.

Comment: When the "Package Installation" window appears, you need to set the "The package will be installed from:" and "The package will be installed for:" fields because they are now empty! In principle, they should not be empty, you have set something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend either of the following remedies to avoid downloading of a package each time you need one:

1. Download Texlive 2022, or the latest version of it available at https://www.tug.org/texlive/, or
2. Download a complete Miktex version, which contains all the packages which used to be available at https://ctan.org/pkg/protext.

Though for me, Texlive is the best. Most of the packages are available all-in-one. For instance, the `fullpage` package is already available in Texlive without any need to do manual installation.

Comment: The essence of the question is what is the reason for the unsuccessful "on-the-fly" installation of the missing package in MiKTeX basic.